# Can't start X probably because of NVidia driver

Tags: x11, nvidia, wayland, nixos

In NixOS, I  successfully installed and started both XMonad, and SwayWM a while ago.   Since then, I have been using only SwayWM, and all seems good. Now I want to explore more about XMonad and so tried to start X with either `xinit` or `startx` from a text virtual console, but failed. See the log below.

- Why did it fail? ( I think it doesn't matter which Linux distribution and window manager, but which graphics driver and which windowing system.)
- How can I  solve the problem, and have both Xmomad and SwayWM on my NixOS?

Here are my settings in `/etc/nixos/configure.nix`

```
services.xserver.videoDrivers = [ "nouveau" ];

# for xmonad
services.xserver.enable = true;
services.xserver.displayManager.startx.enable = true;
services.xserver.windowManager.xmonad.enable = true;

# for sway
programs.sway.enable = true;
```

Here is what `~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log` says:

```
[222528.452] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.11
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[222528.456] Build Operating System: Linux 5.10.63 x86_64 
[222528.458] Current Operating System: Linux o 5.14.10 #1-NixOS SMP Thu Oct 7 05:53:20 UTC 2021 x86_64
[222528.458] Kernel command line: initrd=\efi\nixos\6n6vwn0rgabvla3n303gqbz24mkvj1an-initrd-linux-5.14.10-initrd.efi init=/nix/store/a77hdik4y8ic7lfspkfwr0z0rh6w4ig2-nixos-system-o-21.05.3801.83667ff60a8/init loglevel=4
[222528.461] Build Date: 13 April 2021  02:12:45PM
[222528.462]  
[222528.464] Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
[222528.467]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[222528.467] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[222528.473] (==) Log file: "/home/t/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log", Time: Thu Dec  9 19:04:46 2021
[222528.475] (++) Using config file: "/nix/store/519qmxlgqhl476inzj2pr69wx2ic8rpd-xserver.conf"
[222528.476] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[222528.478] (==) Using system config directory "/nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[222528.479] (==) ServerLayout "Layout[all]"
[222528.480] (**) |-->Screen "Screen-nouveau[0]" (0)
[222528.482] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[222528.483] (**) |   |-->Device "Device-nouveau[0]"
[222528.486] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Screen-nouveau[0]".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[222528.486] (**) Option "DontZap" "on"
[222528.487] (**) Option "AllowMouseOpenFail" "on"
[222528.489] (==) Automatically adding devices
[222528.491] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[222528.492] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[222528.493] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[222528.504] (**) FontPath set to:
    /nix/store/alc330ybax4gmq45lbidkxka48jj3rx4-font-misc-misc-1.1.2/lib/X11/fonts/misc,
    /nix/store/981920bhvw5s488n4ni5cp70hwyh6lly-font-cursor-misc-1.0.3/lib/X11/fonts/misc,
    /nix/store/h9gdfcc87gjpgzhzx84x8mwlnxpf6ax2-unifont-13.0.05/share/fonts,
    /nix/store/839i4shv7h5m4afbrmqfy1z87b2k589z-font-bh-lucidatypewriter-100dpi-1.0.3/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi,
    /nix/store/186c0nz02qy4ba6cqclvmp9vgm18phx7-font-bh-lucidatypewriter-75dpi-1.0.3/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi,
    /nix/store/61lr979inaba5460l36prbpln1jzr2qs-font-bh-100dpi-1.0.3/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi,
    /nix/store/0l5jzarr1gjwv5hdiy8mjrz016ggp8zf-font-adobe-100dpi-1.0.3/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi,
    /nix/store/md2b6nr65g4pc8j9y7lpyq5d7a1p0xag-font-adobe-75dpi-1.0.3/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi
[222528.508] (**) ModulePath set to "/nix/store/h2cqrxy7c344bx0d4qn0pndp4nrw9mph-xf86-video-nouveau-1.0.17/lib/xorg/modules/drivers,/nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/lib/xorg/modules,/nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/lib/xorg/modules/drivers,/nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/lib/xorg/modules/extensions,/nix/store/84qa9n4j9md8agckgy5gkmzlj98mv64k-xf86-input-evdev-2.10.6/lib/xorg/modules/input,/nix/store/70n9l61acjxic0kqh0c41snn7j0ada82-xf86-input-libinput-1.0.1/lib/xorg/modules/input"
[222528.511] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[222528.512] (II) Loader magic: 0x62cd40
[222528.514] (II) Module ABI versions:
[222528.515]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[222528.516]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[222528.518]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[222528.519]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[222528.522] (++) using VT number 4

[222528.524] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_33
[222528.525] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[222530.247] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 13 paused 0
[222530.247] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[222530.248] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card1 226:1 fd 14 paused 0
[222530.250] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:191b:1028:0706 rev 6, Mem @ 0xdd000000/16777216, 0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[222530.250] (--) PCI: (2@0:0:0) 10de:139b:1028:0706 rev 162, Mem @ 0xde000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[222530.250] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[222530.250] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[222530.250] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[222530.250] (II) Loading /nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[222530.251] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[222530.251]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.0.0
[222530.251]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[222530.251] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[222530.251] (II) Loading /nix/store/h2cqrxy7c344bx0d4qn0pndp4nrw9mph-xf86-video-nouveau-1.0.17/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[222530.251] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[222530.251]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.0.17
[222530.251]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[222530.251]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[222530.251] (II) NOUVEAU driver 
[222530.251] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[222530.251]    RIVA TNT            (NV04)
[222530.251]    RIVA TNT2           (NV05)
[222530.251]    GeForce 256         (NV10)
[222530.251]    GeForce 2           (NV11, NV15)
[222530.251]    GeForce 4MX         (NV17, NV18)
[222530.251]    GeForce 3           (NV20)
[222530.251]    GeForce 4Ti         (NV25, NV28)
[222530.251]    GeForce FX          (NV3x)
[222530.251]    GeForce 6           (NV4x)
[222530.251]    GeForce 7           (G7x)
[222530.251]    GeForce 8           (G8x)
[222530.251]    GeForce 9           (G9x)
[222530.251]    GeForce GTX 2xx/3xx (GT2xx)
[222530.251]    GeForce GTX 4xx/5xx (GFxxx)
[222530.251]    GeForce GTX 6xx/7xx (GKxxx)
[222530.251]    GeForce GTX 9xx     (GMxxx)
[222530.251]    GeForce GTX 10xx    (GPxxx)
[222530.251] (II) [drm] nouveau interface version: 1.3.1
[222530.251] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[222530.251] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[222530.251] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[222530.251] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[222530.252] (--) NOUVEAU(0): Chipset: "NVIDIA NV117"
[222530.252] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Screen-nouveau[0]" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[222530.252] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[222530.252] (==) NOUVEAU(0): RGB weight 888
[222530.252] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[222530.252] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Using HW cursor
[222530.252] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Allowed maximum DRI level 2.
[222530.252] (==) NOUVEAU(0): GLX sync to VBlank enabled.
[222530.252] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Page flipping enabled
[222530.252] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Swap limit set to 1 [Max allowed 2]
[222530.252] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Page flipping synced to vblank by kernel.
[222530.252] (WW) NOUVEAU(0): No outputs definitely connected, trying again...
[222530.252] (WW) NOUVEAU(0): Unable to find connected outputs - setting 1024x768 initial framebuffer
[222530.252] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[222530.252] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Virtual size is 1024x768 (pitch 0)
[222530.252] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Mode "1024x768": 63.5 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 47.8 kHz, 59.9 Hz
[222530.252] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x59.9   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync (47.8 kHz)
[222530.252] (==) NOUVEAU(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[222530.252] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[222530.252] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[222530.252] (II) Loading /nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[222530.252] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[222530.252]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.0.0
[222530.252]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[222530.252] (II) Loading sub module "shadowfb"
[222530.252] (II) LoadModule: "shadowfb"
[222530.252] (II) Loading /nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/lib/xorg/modules/libshadowfb.so
[222530.252] (II) Module shadowfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[222530.252]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 1.0.0
[222530.252]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[222530.253] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Channel setup complete.
[222530.253] (II) NOUVEAU(0): [COPY] async initialised.
[222530.254] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Hardware support for Present enabled
[222530.254] (II) NOUVEAU(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[222530.254] (II) NOUVEAU(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: nouveau
[222530.254] (II) NOUVEAU(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nouveau
[222530.254] (II) Loading sub module "exa"
[222530.254] (II) LoadModule: "exa"
[222530.254] (II) Loading /nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so
[222530.254] (II) Module exa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[222530.254]    compiled for 1.20.11, module version = 2.6.0
[222530.254]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[222530.254] (II) EXA(0): Driver allocated offscreen pixmaps
[222530.254] (II) EXA(0): Driver registered support for the following operations:
[222530.254] (II)         Solid
[222530.254] (II)         Copy
[222530.254] (II)         Composite (RENDER acceleration)
[222530.254] (II)         UploadToScreen
[222530.254] (II)         DownloadFromScreen
[222530.254] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Backing store enabled
[222530.254] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Silken mouse enabled
[222530.254] (II) NOUVEAU(0): [XvMC] Associated with Nouveau GeForce 8/9 Textured Video.
[222530.254] (II) NOUVEAU(0): [XvMC] Extension initialized.
[222530.254] (==) NOUVEAU(0): DPMS enabled
[222530.254] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[222530.254] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[222530.254] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[222530.254] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[222530.254] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[222530.254] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[222530.254] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[222530.254] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[222530.255] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[222530.255] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[222530.255] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[222530.255] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[222530.255] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[222530.255] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[222530.255] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[222530.255] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[222530.255] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[222530.255] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[222530.255] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[222530.255] (II) Initializing extension Present
[222530.255] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[222530.255] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[222530.256] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[222530.256] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[222530.256] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[222530.284] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized nouveau
[222530.284] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[222530.284] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[222530.284] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[222530.284] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[222530.284] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[222530.285] (II) NOUVEAU(0): NVEnterVT is called.
[222530.285] (EE) 
[222530.285] (EE) Backtrace:
[222530.285] (EE) 0: /nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/bin/X (OsSigHandler+0x25) [0x5a3025]
[222530.285] (EE) 1: /nix/store/jsp3h3wpzc842j0rz61m5ly71ak6qgdn-glibc-2.32-54/lib/libpthread.so.0 (funlockfile+0x50) [0x7fe5d309f700]
[222530.285] (EE) 2: /nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/bin/X (xf86RandR12CreateScreenResources+0x51c) [0x4c057c]
[222530.285] (EE) 3: /nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/bin/X (xf86CrtcCreateScreenResources+0x40) [0x4b2c20]
[222530.285] (EE) 4: /nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/bin/X (dix_main+0x239) [0x445f99]
[222530.286] (EE) 5: /nix/store/jsp3h3wpzc842j0rz61m5ly71ak6qgdn-glibc-2.32-54/lib/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7fe5d2ef2ded]
[222530.286] (EE) 6: /nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/bin/X (_start+0x2a) [0x42f8aa]
[222530.286] (EE) 
[222530.286] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[222530.286] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[222530.286] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[222530.286] (EE) 
[222530.286] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[222530.286] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/t/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
[222530.286] (EE) 
[222530.286] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[222530.286] (II) NOUVEAU(0): NVLeaveVT is called.
[222530.293] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Changing

```
services.xserver.videoDrivers = [ "nouveau" ];
```

to

```
services.xserver.videoDrivers = [ "nvidia" ];
```

will cause problem to run Sway, as well as to run X and Xmonad.

Is it possible and do I need to change the driver to

```
services.xserver.videoDrivers = [ "nvidia" "nouveau" ];
```

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This here

```
[222530.285] (EE) Backtrace:
[222530.285] (EE) 0: /nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/bin/X (OsSigHandler+0x25) [0x5a3025]
[222530.285] (EE) 1: /nix/store/jsp3h3wpzc842j0rz61m5ly71ak6qgdn-glibc-2.32-54/lib/libpthread.so.0 (funlockfile+0x50) [0x7fe5d309f700]
[222530.285] (EE) 2: /nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/bin/X (xf86RandR12CreateScreenResources+0x51c) [0x4c057c]
[222530.285] (EE) 3: /nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/bin/X (xf86CrtcCreateScreenResources+0x40) [0x4b2c20]
[222530.285] (EE) 4: /nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/bin/X (dix_main+0x239) [0x445f99]
[222530.286] (EE) 5: /nix/store/jsp3h3wpzc842j0rz61m5ly71ak6qgdn-glibc-2.32-54/lib/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7fe5d2ef2ded]
[222530.286] (EE) 6: /nix/store/vdlqhw6zcaw08b1z33iv5nd41w729gd0-xorg-server-1.20.11/bin/X (_start+0x2a) [0x42f8aa]
[222530.286] (EE) 
[222530.286] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
```

Something went horribly, horribly wrong when trying to execute code inside the `nouveau` driver.

Possible reasons:

- Mismatching packages and libraries, some part was built with reference to a different version of some other part (glibc, the X server, your driver). I don't know what package manager nix uses; check all your versions and see if they match, check dependencies, re-install packages as necessary.
- The `nouveau` driver doesn't support your particular hardware. Upgrade to newest version of `nouveau` driver, if it still doesn't work, file a bug report with the developers.

> services.xserver.videoDrivers = [ "nvidia" "nouveau" ];

Your hardware can only be used by **one** driver, either the closed-source nvidia driver, or the open-source nouveau driver.

Comment: Thanks.  SwayWM works, but not X. Can the driver not work with the graphics card?

Comment: I am neither using NixOS, nor SwayWM, nor XMonad, so I can't say what and what doesn't work, or is supposed to work or not, and why. Quickly googling for SwayWM says it's a Wayland compositor, so it won't work with X, at all, but that's just me doing a 10 second google.

Comment: My comment raised the following question: can the driver work for SwayMM but not X, if it caused the problem?